# use raw string, instead of escape string, in ggpub::ggboxplot of R

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr, ggpubr, ggboxplot

How to use the raw string (such as len/s) in the colnames in `ggpubr::ggboxplot` in R? It seems due to `purrr::map`

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

colnames(df) <- c("len/s", "supp", "dose%sd")

ggboxplot(df, x = "dose%sd", y = 'len/s',
               color = "dose%sd", palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
               add = "jitter", shape = "dose%sd")
```

with error

```
Error in `purrr::pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: len/s.
Caused by error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: x.
Caused by error in `parse()`:
! <text>:1:5: unexpected input
1: dose%sd

---
Backtrace:
  1. ggpubr::ggboxplot(...)
 15. purrr::map(., function(x) parse_expression(x))
 16. purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
 20. ggpubr (local) .f(.x[[i]], ...)
 21. ggpubr:::parse_expression(x)
 22. base::parse(text = x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `parse_aes` option is set to `TRUE`.

```
> ggpubr_options()
$ggpubr.parse_aes
[1] TRUE
```

We could set the `parse_aes` options to `FALSE` and reset after the plotting

```
library(ggpubr)
op <- options(ggpubr.parse_aes = FALSE)
colnames(df) <- c("len/s", "supp", "dose%sd")

ggboxplot(df, x = "dose%sd", y = 'len/s',
          color = "dose%sd", palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
          add = "jitter", shape = "dose%sd")

options(op)
```

-output

[image]

---

`ggboxplot` calls `ggboxplot_core` internal function, which calls the `ggplot` with `create_aes` where `parse = TRUE`

```
> ggpubr:::ggboxplot_core
...
p <- ggplot(data, create_aes(list(x = x, y = y)))
...
> create_aes
function (.list, parse = TRUE) 
{
    if (missing(parse)) {
        parse <- base::getOption("ggpubr.parse_aes", default = TRUE)
    }
    if (parse) {
        return(create_aes.parse(.list))
    }
    else {
        return(create_aes.name(.list))
    }
}
```

The `create_aes.parse` calls the `parse_expression` whereas the `create_aes.name` converts to symbol

```
> ggpubr:::create_aes.parse
function (.list) 
{
    .list <- .list %>% purrr::map(function(x) parse_expression(x))
    do.call(ggplot2::aes, .list)
}

> ggpubr:::create_aes.name
function (.list) 
{
    .list <- .list %>% purrr::map(function(x) to_name(x))
    do.call(ggplot2::aes, .list)
}
```

Therefore, it is easier to set the `parse_aes` to `FALSE`

Comment: Thank you. ggpubr v0.50 changed the default value of this parameter as shown in ggpubr.parse_aes.  Ref: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpubr/news/news.html